# scp -O (legacy protocol) option per config file?

Tags: ssh, scp

I basically have the same problem as described (and solved) [over at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74311661/subsystem-request-failed-on-channel-0-scp-connection-closed-macbook). This is: `scp` to some hosts which do not support SFTP subsystem is only working if I provide the `-O` flag.

However is there a way to instead configure this behavior *by default*? E.g. by an option in `~/.ssh/config` ?

The point is: For manual use I can just use an `alias scp='scp -O'`, however this won't work in scripts and non-shell actions (such as running ansible playbooks).

Comment: Crossposted: https://superuser.com/q/1809629/213663

Comment: Please [do not cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/355310).